# How to get the Content of selected Menu Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, hierarchicaldatatemplate

## Summary of the problem

### Goal

My goal is to create a Navigation menu in WPF.

The navigation items are built in the View Model using Nodes.

Selected `SubItem` of the menu will display the content of the selected Node.

### Expected and actual result

This is what I have built so far:

[image]

### Error

Now I need to present the selected `MenuItem` to `ContentPresenter` - and this is where I have the problem with.

## What I have tried

This is my current code

XAML

```
<!--Menu-->
<Menu x:Name="NavigationTreeView" IsMainMenu="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Navigation}" Grid.Row="0">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VsMenuTop}" />
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type nav:PageViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>

<!--Content-->
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=NavigationTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

This will not work, because I am not able to bind it to Menu using this line here: `SelectedItem.Content` - and the Menu does not have a property `SelectedItem`.

### Alternative

My alternative option would be to use `ListView`, because it contains a property `SelectedItem`. But preferably I'd like to use `Menu`.

## Question

How can I get the selected item from the Hierarchical Data Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Menu` control does not have a notion of a selected item, as its `MenuItem`s are essentially buttons that should execute an action when clicked. You can set the [`IsCheckable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischeckable?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.IsCheckable);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) property to `true` to be a able to *check* menu items like a `CheckBox`, but I guess that does not fit your use-case here.

Since you probably want to display different content depending on which menu item was clicked, you could use a command, that is executed when you click a `MenuItem` and gets the corresponding view model as parameter and sets a property on a view model that can be bound by the `ContentPresenter`.

Introduce a `Selected` property of type `PageViewModel` and a `Select` command in your main view model that contains the `Navigation` porperty. The command sets the `Selected` property.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainViewModel()
   {
      Selected = new RelayCommand<PageViewModel>(pageViewModel => Selected = pageViewModel);
      // ...other code.
   }

   public DelegateCommand<PageViewModel> Select { get; }
   
   private PageViewModel _selected;
   public PageViewModel Selected
   {
      get => _selected;
      private set
      {
         if (_selected == value)
            return;
   
         _selected = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
   
   // ...other code.
}
```

You can replace the `RelayCommand` by the command implementation that you have at your disposal.

Then, you can adapt your style to bind the command on the main view model (either using `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` to the data context) and to bind the view model of the clicked `MenuItem` as command parameter. This way it is passed to the command, which sets it as `Selected`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
   <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VsMenuTop}" />
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.Select, ElementName=NavigationTreeView}"/>
   <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
</Style>
```

Bind the `Content` of your `ContentPresenter` to the `Selected` property on the main view model.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=NavigationTreeView, Path=Selected}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Сan think of many implementations, but it is not entirely clear what you need.
Additional details required.

SelectedItem (property of the Selector class) contains not a UI element, but a collection source element.
Maybe you too need it , not a MenuItem?

You are not using commands, so you can use them to solve the problem.

I have implemented a simple proxy using [BaseInpc and RelayCommand classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597202/how-to-fix-this-behavior-in-a-wpf-tabcontrol/67617794#67617794).

```
using Simplified;

namespace SelectedItem
{
    public class SelectedItemProxy : BaseInpc
    {
        private object _selectedMenuItem;

        public object SelectedMenuItem { get => _selectedMenuItem; set => Set(ref _selectedMenuItem, value); }

        private RelayCommand _selectItemCommand;
        public RelayCommand SelectItemCommand => _selectItemCommand
            ?? (_selectItemCommand = new RelayCommand(item => SelectedMenuItem = item));
    }
}
```

An example of its use:

```
<Window x:Class="SelectedItem.SmiExamleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectedItem"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SmiExamleWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SelectedItemProxy x:Key="proxy"/>
        
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="NavigationTreeView" IsMainMenu="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Navigation}" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Menu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectItemCommand, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.Resources>
            <sys:String>First</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Second</sys:String>
        </Menu>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```