# How to unselect a listview item when creating a new item collection? Im using observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem

Im having a hard time with the following error:
I have a listview that is binded to an observable collection.
Lets say it looks like this:

XAMl:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}">
```

ViewModel:

```
 private Field selecteditem;
    public Field selectedItem { 
        get { return selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            selecteditem = value;    
        }
... //other code parts
myCollection = customClass.fillCollection(selectedLightColor, selectedDarkColor);
```

When i click on an item it is selected. When i click on another that is the selected one. This is totally okay. However at a certain point i need to recreate the whole observable collection that is connected to this listview.
If i didnt select anything it recreates the collection perfectly.
But, when i have a selected item it throws a System.NullReferenceException error to the property that is binded to the SelectedItem of the listview.
For the recreation im using the same code mentioned above (myCollection = customClass...)
I cant find a solution that solves the problem.
I have tried myCollection.Clear() and also selectedItem = null, but the error remained the same.
Im glad to hear any help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem you describe, but it didn't work for me.
My example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core2022.SO.freasy
{
    public class Field
    {
        public int Number { get; } = random.Next();
        private static readonly Random random = new Random();

        public static IEnumerable<Field> GetRandomFields()
            => Enumerable.Range(0, random.Next(10, 20)).Select(_ => new Field()).ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

```cs
using Simplified;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Core2022.SO.freasy
{
    public class FieldsViewModel : BaseInpc
    {
        private IEnumerable<Field> _fields = Field.GetRandomFields();
        private RelayCommand? _refreshFields;

        public IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get => _fields; set => Set(ref _fields, value); }

        public RelayCommand RefreshFields => _refreshFields
            ??= new RelayCommand(_ => Fields = Field.GetRandomFields());

        private Field? _selectedField;
        public Field? SelectedField
        {
            get => _selectedField;
            set => Set(ref _selectedField, value);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.freasy.FieldsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.freasy" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FieldsWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:FieldsViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="null">No Selected Field</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Number"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedField}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <PriorityBinding>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedField.Number" Mode="OneWay"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource null}"/>
                    </PriorityBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <PriorityBinding>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Number" Mode="OneWay" ElementName="listBox"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource null}"/>
                    </PriorityBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
            <Button Content="Refresh Collection" Command="{Binding RefreshFields}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="15 5"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Perhaps you missed an important detail of your implementation in the explanations, which is the cause of the error you described.
Try changing my simple example to reproduce your problem.

[BaseInpc and RelayCommand classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67617794/13349759)
[Source Code Archive: freasy.7z](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ctsKZ9CsvsSbmeMDjdSYqMOxb4WcTHtK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for trying to code an example, but i cant even make this work. My observable collection (myCollection in my example) gets recreated when i press a button. As i said it works perfectly when i never select an item. For some reason i have to unselect the selected item to avoid NullReferenceError when recreating the collection. I just cant figure out how i can do that. I have only seen code examples that dont follow the MVVM pattern and just change it in code-behind.

Comment: @freasy ,Hi! I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. And without that, I can't tell you how to fix it.
I supplemented the answer with a link to the answer with the implementation of the base classes and the archive with the source codes. The code is fully debugged and working.

Comment: Sorry for replying late! Thank you again for taking a look at my problem, but I just couldnt make your code work. It gave me many error, including i dont use the correct C# version. I solved the problem (and will answer my own question now), I just forgot to reply, because i had been busy.

Answer (score 0):

Because the property setter called a method which used my private variable (selecteditem) the program couldnt handle the selecteditem variable to be null!

I can finally recreate my collection by adding a statement to the setter:

```
private Field selecteditem;
public Field selectedItem { 
    get { return selecteditem; }
    set
    {
       selecteditem = value;
       if (selecteditem != null)
       {
           //call method and do stuffs
       }
            
    }
```