# Popup shows up multiple times in listview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listview, popup

I am working on a project in WPF. I have listview control and in that listview I have textblock and button as a template controls.

I want that when user click the button the popup open and shows the infos of selected item. But when clicked the button popup shows up multiple times (count of items).

These are the XAML codes.

```
<Window x:Class="TestingPopupShow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestingPopupShow.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingPopupShow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ItemInfosPopupVM x:Key="vm"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    
   
        <Grid   x:Name="SubGrid" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView  x:Name="listView" 
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="0 5 0 0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="debugPanel"  CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"  x:Name="listViewGrid" Margin="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Background="#F2F2F2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="W01"
                                               FontSize="12"
                                               Margin="5"
                                               FontFamily="Tohama"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1 pcs"
                                               FontSize="12"
                                               Margin="5"
                                               FontFamily="Tohama"/>


                                    <TextBlock Text="1200 X 1600"
                                               FontSize="12"
                                               Margin="5"
                                               FontFamily="Tohama"/>
                                </StackPanel >

                                <DockPanel x:Name="imageDockPanel" Grid.Column="1">

                                </DockPanel >
                                <Button Grid.Column="2"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                                Command="{Binding showPopupCommand}"
                                            x:Name="buttonOpen" 
                                            Content=">"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="itemInfosPopup" 
                                                   
                                              StaysOpen="False"
                                               Placement="Mouse"
                                               IsOpen="{Binding PopupVis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                               AllowsTransparency="True">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                                        <StackPanel Background="White" Width="200" Height="300">

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

This the ViewModel Class

```
public class ItemInfosPopupVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool popupVis;
    public bool PopupVis
    {
        get { return popupVis; }
        set
        {
            popupVis = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PopupVis");
        }
    }
    
    public ShowPopupCommand showPopupCommand { get; set; }
    public ItemInfosPopupVM()
    {
        PopupVis = false;
        showPopupCommand = new ShowPopupCommand(this);
    }
       
    public void ShowPopup()
    {
        if (PopupVis)
        {
            PopupVis = false;
        }
        else
        {
            PopupVis = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

These are command class:

```
public class ShowPopupCommand : ICommand
{
    public ItemInfosPopupVM ViewModel { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public ShowPopupCommand(ItemInfosPopupVM vm)
    {
        ViewModel = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ViewModel.ShowPopup();
    }
}
```

These are temporary codes for testing in the main window view

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Temporary codes. Testing listview.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            listView.Items.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I think I'm creating the popup control in the wrong place in XAML. But i can not figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly implement the data context (ViewModel) and commands.
Here's an example based on base classes from here: [BaseInpc and RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67617794/13349759).

```cs
    public class ItemInfosPopupVM : BaseInpc
    {
        private bool popupVis;
        private string title = string.Empty;

        public bool PopupVis { get => popupVis; set => Set(ref popupVis, value); }

        public string Title { get => title; set => Set(ref title, value ?? string.Empty); }
    }
```

```cs
    public class ItemsVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemInfosPopupVM> ItemInfos { get; } = new();

        public ItemsVM()
        {
            // Temporary codes. Testing listview.
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ItemInfos.Add(new ItemInfosPopupVM { Title = "Item " + i.ToString() });
            }

            InvertPopupVis = new RelayCommand<ItemInfosPopupVM>
            (
                item => item.PopupVis = !item.PopupVis
            );
        }

        public RelayCommand<ItemInfosPopupVM> InvertPopupVis { get; }
    }
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestingPopupShow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestingPopupShow.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingPopupShow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="400"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ItemsVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid   x:Name="SubGrid" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemInfos}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="0 5 0 0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ItemInfosPopupVM}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Grid Margin="1"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Background="#F2F2F2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='{}{0} - W01'}"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Margin="5"
                                           FontFamily="Tohama"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="1 pcs"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Margin="5"
                                           FontFamily="Tohama"/>


                                <TextBlock Text="1200 X 1600"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Margin="5"
                                           FontFamily="Tohama"/>
                            </StackPanel >

                            <DockPanel x:Name="imageDockPanel" Grid.Column="1">

                            </DockPanel >
                            <Button Grid.Column="2"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Command="{Binding InvertPopupVis, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Content=">"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Popup StaysOpen="False"
                                   Placement="Mouse"
                                   IsOpen="{Binding PopupVis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   AllowsTransparency="True">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                                    <StackPanel Background="White" Width="200" Height="300">

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: I added BaseInc and RelayCommand classes from link you shared. Then i change my codes with yours and run the program. I clicked the button but popup is not shown.

Comment: @Gokhan, My code has been verified by me. The result is in the screenshot in my answer. Perhaps you copied something incorrectly or for some other reason.
If possible, upload the entire Solution to GitHub. I will check it.

Comment: I examined the codes in more detail and tried it again. It works perfectly. Many thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your popup control from `ListView` control like this and add `selection changed` Event in `ListView` control like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="SubGrid" Grid.Column="1">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListView SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" ... />
 <Popup x:Name="itemInfosPopup" 
        StaysOpen="False"
        Placement="Mouse"
        IsOpen="{Binding PopupVis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
           <StackPanel Background="White" Width="200" Height="300">

           </StackPanel>
 </Border>
 </Popup>
```

Now in that event you need to open popup control for only selected item and not for all(as this is this is your requirement):

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        itemInfosPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        itemInfosPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
   
}
```

and that is it.

IMPORTANT: This only opens a single popup and now you need to handle closing and opening another one on selection changed(when you click and select other item). Your task was to open a single one for a selected item :) and be careful because popup control handling can be tricky.

Comment: many thanx for attention. With your suggestion Popup appears when the item is selected. But i want by clicking the button.

Comment: I pointed it to the selection changed event becasue I wanted to show where you should focus be(and your question is how to open a single one instread of number of counted times) and now it is easy to switch the logic to anywhere else and finally be careful where you will put IsOpen = False when changing to another element in ListView control. @Gokhan

Comment: Himm thanx, I will heed your warnings. Now i ll use @EldHasp solution and try to bind data to listbox. It doesn't look like it will be easy as you said.

Comment: About that opening/closing handling(in short). Opening is now clear and you must close it when you click other selected item and code some validations related to that and be careful to define what should close your popup. For example, if you open your popup control and it stays open I think that you should make some mouse up or prevew mouse up button click event and close it and then open a new one which is selected and I can update some code later if you are interested? @Gokhan

Comment: With EldHasp solution is working perfectly there is no need to implement closing. It is automaticly closing if clicking outside or other items. There is no problem for now. Thanx for attention.

Comment: All right and I am glad I helped you @Gokhan.