# WPF binded data in my ListBox is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create WPF application following MVVM pattern everithing was ok till i started binding commands changing the data. I don't understand why after the command executing info in my ListBox is not updating.

here is my ViewModel:

```cs
class FirstVM : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<DetailScheme> _detailsScheme;
    private string _text;
    private ObservableCollection<Material> _materials;
    private ObservableCollection<Detail> _detail;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DetailScheme> DetailScheme 
    { 
        get { return _detailsScheme; } 
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials 
    {
        get { return _materials; } 
        set { 
                _materials = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details 
    { 
        get { return _detail; } 
        set { 
                _detail = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
            }
    }
    public RelayCommand ProduceCommand { get; set; }

    public FirstVM () 
    {
        _detailsScheme = GetDetailsScheme("D:/ DetailsScheme.json");
        _materials = GetMaterials("D:/ Materials.json");
        _detail = GetDetails("D:/ Details.json");
        ProduceCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
        {
                        //this method return new ObservableCollection
            Materials = GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch(Materials, (o as DetailScheme).Materials);
                Text = Materials[0].ToString();
        });
        
    }
```

Material class:

```cs
    class Material : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _amount;
    
        public int Amount { 
            get { return _amount; }
            set { 
                    _amount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }  
            }
    
        public string Name { 
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    
        public Material(string name, int amount)
        {
            _name = name;
            _amount = amount;
        }
        
        public static ObservableCollection<Material> GetMaterials(string path)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Material> materials;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                materials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Material>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            return materials;
        }
        public static ObservableCollection <Material> GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch(ObservableCollection<Material> allMaterials, ObservableCollection<Material> requiredMaterials)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allMaterials.Count; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < requiredMaterials.Count; j++)
                    if (allMaterials[i].Name == requiredMaterials[j].Name)
                        allMaterials[i].Amount -= requiredMaterials[j].Amount;
            return allMaterials;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name+$" : {Amount}";
        }
    }
```

and View:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Storage_Manager.MVVM.View.Task_1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Storage_Manager.MVVM.View"
             xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Storage_Manager.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Storage_Manager.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="515" d:DesignWidth="700">
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <VM:FirstVM/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox x:Name="BoxOfDetails"
                      Height="50" 
                      Width="250"  
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      Margin="10,10,440,455"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DetailScheme}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontSize="9" Margin="0,7,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
            <Button Content ="Produce"
                    Width="200"
                    Margin="60,460,440,10"
                    Command="{Binding ProduceCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BoxOfDetails, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" 
                     Background="Transparent" 
                     Foreground="white"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray"
               Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

I added TextBlock to see if the information is updating after click on the Button, and yes in my TextBlock data is changing after each click, but ListBox remains unchanged. Material class implements  the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Updating the collection and updating the data in the collection are different things. Do you apply OnPropertyChanged to your data in the Material class?

Comment: From your code and its explanations, it is not clear what the error might be.
For diagnostic purposes, try replacing the collection in command this way:  `Materials = new ObservableCollection<Material>() {/* 2-3 some elements */}`.

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz yes,  every property that changes is used OnPropertyChanged

Comment: @EldHasp if to write like in your example everything works ok, does it mean that the problem is in GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch method?

Comment: In `GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch` you don't actually create a new collection, you just change the `Amount` value of some items. So you could make that method even `void`.
The changes to`Amount` should however be reflected by the ListBox since `Amount` notifies on its change. 
Do you have binding errors in the Output window in VS?
Is the code shown the true complete code or a reduction?

Comment: What is the implementation of `OnPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @lidqy only xaml code is reduction, but other elemets in xaml code have nothing common with shown(some other buttons and textblocks)

Comment: @lidqy 
`class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) 
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }  
}`

Comment: @Zahar okay `OnPropertyChanged` is just the way it should be

Comment: You need an explicit property to bind your listbox items to in either in `DisplayMemberPath` or in a `ItemTemplate`. Currently you bind to the result of `Material.ToString()` which does not raise `PropertyChanged` bc it is a method. Also the collection isn't changed in `GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch` so also `CollectionChanged` isn't fired. That is why the data in the UI remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trouble is that you don't bind to an Material item's property directly, but just let ToString() do the work, which is straight forward to get your data displayed, but lacks change notifications.
A XAML only solution, leaving the C# code untouched, would be:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" 
                     Background="Transparent" 
                     Foreground="white"
                     BorderThickness="0"                     
                     IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <!-- ToDo tweak Widths by yourself according to you
                   material name and amout values widths, so that they look nicely aligned -->
                  <TextBlock MinWidth="150" Text={Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                  <TextBlock MinWidth="100" Text={Binding Amount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N0}" 
                             TextAlignment="Right" />
              </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You might as well add a "DisplayText" string property to Material class and have it return Name + Amount like ToString now does, and use it as `DisplayMemberPath` of the ListBox.

Another solution would be to create a `new ObservableCollection`in GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch and not to return the allMaterials collection passed in. Then the UI update would go via CollectionChanged. But it is actually not a recommendation to recreate a new collection if only item member data changes.

Comment: yeeeees,thanks a lot, evetithing works now

Comment: Thanks, glad to help, greetz from germany to belarus

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional clarification in the comments, I'm guessing you need to use code like this:

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials {get;} = new();

    public RelayCommand ProduceCommand { get;}

    public FirstVM () 
    {
        _detailsScheme = GetDetailsScheme("D:/ DetailsScheme.json");
        _materials = GetMaterials("D:/ Materials.json");
        _detail = GetDetails("D:/ Details.json");
        ProduceCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
        {
                        //this method return new ObservableCollection
            _materials = GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch(Materials, (o as DetailScheme).Materials);
            Materials.Clear();
            foreach(var m in _materials)
            {
                Materials.Add(m);
            }
            Text = Materials[0].ToString();
        });
        
    }
```

**P.S.**  But I still have big doubts about the “Get” method. Judging by the parameters and name, you get a projection of the Materials collection in it. The next time it is called, it will be a projection of a projection, and then the chain of projections will grow and grow.
If you can explain the logic behind this method, perhaps I can suggest a better solution to implement it.

**Adding to the answer, after adding the Material class code.**

1. Take the Mshu base class codes [BaseInpc and RelayCommand classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67617794/13349759)
2. Add a property to display the Material display view and a notification when it changes.

```cs
    public class Material : BaseInpc
    {
        private string _name = string.Empty;
        private int _amount;

        public int Amount { get => _amount; set => Set(ref _amount, value); }
        public string Name { get => _name; set => Set(ref _name, value ?? string.Empty); }

        public Material(string name, int amount)
        {
            Name = name;
            Amount = amount;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + $" : {Amount}";
        }

        public string DisplayName => ToString();

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object? oldValue, object? newValue)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayName));
        }
```

3. The "GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch" method should not return a collection, it simply modifies the one passed to it.

```cs
        public static void GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch(IEnumerable<Material> allMaterials, IEnumerable<Material> requiredMaterials)
        {
            foreach (Material  material in allMaterials)
            {
                foreach (var req in requiredMaterials)
                {
                     if (material.Name == req.Name)
                        material.Amount -= req.Amount;
                }
            }
        }
```

4. ListBox outputs ToString() value by default and this value is not updated. Therefore, you need to set the property value to be displayed with a change notification.

```xml
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" 
             Background="Transparent" 
             Foreground="white"
             BorderThickness="0"
             IsHitTestVisible="False"
             DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>
```

5. The command does not need to change the collection itself. You only need to change the property values of its elements:

```
        ProduceCommand = new RelayCommand<DetailScheme>(ds => 
        {
                        //this method return new ObservableCollection
            GetMaterialsAfterNormalBatch(Materials, ds.Materials);
            Text = Materials[0].ToString();
        });
```

6. The Text property also seems unnecessary to me. This value can be obtained directly in XAML:

```xml
    <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray"
               Text="{Binding Materials[0].DisplayName}"/>
```